# Help in this proof in Hungerford's book

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to understand this part in the proof:

[image]

In the last line: If $i\le r$, ok! but if $i\gt r$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, the orbits are ordered such that the one-element orbits are at the end: the $B_i$ for $r<i\leq s$. So $x\in B_i$ with $i>r$ implies $B_i=\{x\}$ and therefore $\sigma(x)=x$, and one also has $\sigma_1\sigma_2\ldots\sigma_r(x)=x$ since $\sigma_j(x)=x$ for $j=r,\ldots,2,1$ (because $x\notin B_j$ by disjointness).